# what is the last value of variable in cycle for

Tags: java

What is the last value of i - 10 or 11?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)  {}
```

and what is for

```
cycle while (i<=10) do {}
```

Comment: @AmitD I'll tell you my reason: insufficient research. This is trivial to check.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think the confusion is because of scope. But yes he should check it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: `i = 11`

For the second one: `i = 11` too.

You can test this by declaring `i` outside of the loops, and then printing its value once the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

what does say the following code:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {}
System.out.println(i);

while (i<=10) do {} is an unknown java construct, there is no such thing
```

you can say

`while (i<=10) { }` 
but it would be an infinite loop, the value of i would be the same before executing the while loop

Comment: Only the last line is invalid, and trivially fixable by transposing `while` and `do`.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)  {}` Last value is 11

`cycle while (i<=10) do {}` Last value is also 11